# How to declare a 3DArray in Row Major Order?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've written a class that stores 2D arrays as 1D arrays and overloads the index operator as follows:

```
inline T* operator [](const int Index) {return Data.get() + Height * Index;}
```

Where Data is an `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`.

This allows me to do: `MyInstance[I][J]` to get values as row major order and `MyInstance[J][I]` to get values as column major order.

How can I do the same with a 3D array? I'm trying to figure out how it is laid out in memory so I did:

```
int main()
{
    //index = [i + width * (j + depth * k)];

    const int width = 4, height = 4, depth = 4;

    int l = 0;
    int ptr[width][height][depth] = {0}; //Same as int ptr[width * height * depth]; ?
    //int ptr[height][width][depth]??    


    for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)  //i < ??
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) //j < ??
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k) //k < ??
            {
                ptr[i][j][k] = l++;
            }
        }
    }

    int* p = &ptr[0][0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k)
            {
                std::cout<<p[i + width * (j + depth * k)]<<"\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, it does NOT print in the right order. It seems to be printing in a random order or column major order.

I wasn't sure how to declare the array:

```
int arr[depth][height][width];
int arr[width][height][depth];
int arr[height][width][depth];
int arr[depth][width][height];
int arr[height][depth][width];
int arr[width][depth][height];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you might want to be using `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of `std::unique_ptr<int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > arr;
```

And access would be

```
int arr[depth][height][width];
```

because each `[]` operators returns the `vector` which has an overloaded `[]` operator.

Comment: I solved it doing `arr[k + j*depth + i*depth*height]`

Answer (score 0):

The linear index computations is as follows

```
dim1 + dim2*size1 + dim3*size1*size2
```

Comment: Seems to compute the same indices as what I have on the OP.

Comment: but it should match how you define your matrix and the loop ordering. Choose declaration like `int arr[size1][size2][size3];`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overloading the index operator `operator[]` overload the function operator `operator()` this will allow passing multiple values.

```
inline T& operator ()(int i, int j, int k) { /* return the indexed item here */ }
```